# PHP: Elegant Way To Output This Array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm over complicating the output of this example array, what is the cleanest, most elegant way you would do this for the desired output.

**Array Ex:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [<h4><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></h4>] => <img src="Image_1.jpg" />
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [<h4><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></h4>] => <img src="Image_2.png" />
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [<h4><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></h4>] => <img src="Image_3.png" />
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [<h4><a href="#link3">Link 4</a></h4>] => <img src="Image_4.png" />
        )
)
```

**Desired Output**

```
<h4><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></h4>
<img src="Image_1.jpg" />

<h4><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></h4>
<img src="Image_2.png" />

<h4><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></h4>
<img src="Image_3.png" />

<h4><a href="#link3">Link 4</a></h4>
<img src="Image_4.png" />
```

Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: have you tried using  `$print_r();` or `var_dump();`?

Comment: Look up the `foreach` command

Comment: @SaucedApples - yeah, I'm looking for the described desired output.

Comment: @RiggsFolly - thanks, whilst I was using that, I felt I was overcomplicating it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should do what you want :

```
<?php

foreach ($foo as $bar) {
    foreach($bar as $title => $image) {
        echo $title;
        echo $image;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for the `\n`.. :)

Comment: @sougata yes u r right and I see u removed your answer bro :)

Comment: @sougata yes my friend it's multidimensional

Comment: @Gwendal - perfect. Will mark as answer after the time limit.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
array_walk($arr, function($value,$key){
        array_walk($value, function($v,$k){
            echo $k;
            echo $v;
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to php though i tried my best in bringing up this and i think this would work fine with the sample you provided.

```
<?php
$link1= '<h4><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></h4>';
$link2= '<h4><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></h4>'; 
$image1='<img src="Image_1.jpg"';
$image2='<img src="Image_2.png"';

$elements =  array("$link1"=>"$image1","$link2"=>"$image2");
foreach($elements as $ele =>$ele_value)
{
echo "link=".$ele . ", image=" . $ele_value;
echo "<br>";
}?>
```

Comment: Please see the marked answer. The array I presentenced is not something I can change. Thanks.

Comment: i got your point, but when i tried to execute the array code it throws  syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting ']' , so i used variable instead in array